# Как сделать перенос при отправке словаря в тг?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, словари, dict

Пишу телеграмм бота, использую pytelegrambotapi. Когда я добавляю в словарь элементы `dct[key] = value` и хочу их отправить в тг, то они отправляются по типу:
`{key_1: value_1; key_2: value_2}`.

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы отправлялось так:

`{key_1: value_1;`

`key_2: value_2}`

Comment: Покажите код отправки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто используйте '\n',а еще можно через цикл for,я думаю,раз вы задаете такие вопросы,то наверняка знаете,как это сделать